# Create SQL trigger with two actions

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that will do two things:

1. Copy everything from a row in table X to a row in table Y before an `UPDATE` is done
2. Copy one column from a row in table X to a row in table Y after the `UPDATE` from no. 1 is done

This is what I have until now:

```
delimiter //
create trigger log
before update on opnaar
for each ROW 

    begin
    set @a = opnaar.id;
    set @c = opnaar.initials;
    set @d = opnaar.revised;
    set @f = opnaar.course;
        insert into log(id,init_old,date_old,date_new,course) values (@a,@c,@d,NOW(),@f);
        end;

    after update on opnaar
    for each ROW
    begin
        set @e = opnaar.initials;
            insert into log(init_new) values (@e);
            end;
```

But I figured it's not possible to add just one value to an already existing row in a table. At least, not the way I am trying to do this. Should I place the `after update` within the first action?

Example: I have this content:

[image]

I want to copy `course`, `revised`, `initials` and `id` to another table. That's what my first action should do.

After a teacher has updated something in that table, the NEW initials (but in the same column as the old initials) should be copied to table Y. That's what my 2nd action should do.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What **database system** is this for? Those things are very vendor-specific - can't just say from knowing "SQL" (= Structured Query Language - but that's not a product...)

Comment: It's for MySQL, is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes - updated the tag accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [CREATE TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html) syntax. It is not possible to specify AFTER and BEFORE option in one trigger.

- So, you should create two separate triggers.
- If you want to optimize code and combine trigger's bodies, then you can write a stored proceure and call it from the triggers.